# What is difference between BLOB and tile in GeoPackage?

Tags: tiles, geopackage, terminology

I'm new to GeoPackage, but wrote some code that will read an image file into a buffer and I then insert that buffer into the GeoPackage as a BLOB.

The image files are GeoTIFFs which contain latitude, longitude, elevation data.

So, when reading through the [requirements](http://www.geopackage.org/spec/) for GeoPackage, I see a required table that has a column for BLOB, but then I see a table that has a requirement for tiles.

What is the difference between them?

My BLOB is an area of a map and I do not know if a tile is the exact same thing.

The link from @user30184 is exactly what I needed from the start.  I had been to their website, but never saw the "spec" branch.

Comment: What parts of the GeoPackage standard http://www.geopackage.org/spec/ you are reading? Tiles are rectangular pieces of raster data, cut to suit with the tile matrix and stored into table that holds the tile data, into column named "tile_data" as BLOBs.

Comment: Sorry, indeed I misunderstood your question (voted to reopen). I tried to edit it to make it more clear. Perhaps you can replace that link I added to 'requirements' to pinpoint exactly to what you were reading. Also, you asked and edited with different accounts. If you do that, your edit needs to be approved by other users, but if you edit with the same account from question, the edit is applied instantly. See here to learn how to merge your accounts if you intend continue participating here. https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts